# Объект недвижимости «Световая площадка», расположенн(ый/ая) по адресу

Tags: грамотная-речь

Объект недвижимости «Световая площадка», расположенный по адресу... или Объект недвижимости «Световая площадка», расположенная по адресу...

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае опорным словом является "объект". Именно он расположен, а «Световая площадка» является лишь названием объекта.

Поэтому правильно: Объект недвижимости «Световая площадка», расположенный по адресу...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37384/discussion-on-answer-by------).

Answer (score 1):

Если исходить из общего смысла, то по адресу расположен объект. Поэтому "объект недвижимости ..., расположенный".

Но тут могут быть тонкости. Можно допустить, что таких площадок много и закавычено не название, а условное обозначение, одинаковое для многих таких площадок. В этом случае согласование с "площадка" представляется возможным и даже допустимым. Но тогда надо еще одну пару кавычек ввести, чтобы снять возможные недоразумения

*Объект недвижимости "«Световая площадка», расположенная по адресу... "*
Повторяю, это как малореальный вариант, но возможный.

Реальный вариант: ***объект... расположенный.***

Answer (score 0):

Объект недвижимости «Световая площадка», **расположенный** по адресу.

Схема: нарицательное существительное (родовое наименование) + 
 условное название (имя собственное).

В этом случае используется грамматическое согласование с подлежащим (нарицательным существительным), например: **Местная газета** "Полярник" перестала издаваться. **Пассажирский теплоход** "Грузия" вышел в открытое море.

При наличии кавычек имя собственное выступает в роли несогласованного определения, поэтому  согласование с подлежащим является единственным решением.

Comment: А "подлежащее" - это у вас одно родовое слове? А имя собственное тогда какой член предложения?

Comment: Это не совсем у меня, материал согласован с академическим учебником 2012 года "Практическая стилистика". Там подлежащим названо именно родовое слово. Имя собственное в этом случае часто называют приложением, но это не совсем точно (приложение - это СОГЛАСОВАННОЕ в падеже определение, выраженное существительным). Поэтому можно считать, что «Световая площадка» - это несогласованное определение, выраженное именем собственным.

Comment: А учебник точно академический? Автор у него - академик?

Comment: Это серия учебников, рекомендованных Научно-редакционным советом  академической программы "Словари XXI века". Председатель совета президент РАН академик Ю.С. Осипов.

Comment: Осипов - физик. Словарь кто-то другой написал.)))

Comment: Разумеется, другой. Автор - доктор филологических наук, профессор МГУ Ю. А. Бельчиков.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, спрошу на кафедре, что это за "словарь" и что о нем думают в МГУ))). Как-то не на слуху у меня раньше книга была. Вообще Юлий Абрамович, конечно, голова, но смотреть грамматику в книге по *практической стилистике* - это "что-то особенного"...

Comment: В практической стилистике можно посмотреть  тематику различных согласований, например подлежащего и определения при наличии приложения. В то же время можно предположить, что при этом используется корректная грамматическая терминология, принятая в современном языке.

Comment: Да бога ради, смотрите, где хотите. Показателен сам "выбор репертуара".

Comment: Мне не очень ясна Ваша позиция. Вы можете указать учебник по грамматике, где ясно обозначены синтаксические функции слов в сочетаниях с именем собственным, заключенным в кавычки? Или у Вас нет такого учебника, но вы не согласны с приведенным суждением и у Вас есть своя точка зрения? Тогда, пожалуйста, выскажите ее.

Comment: Нет, я не могу указать такого учебника. Но я могу указать на то, что не вижу большой разницы, будет ли это собственное заключено в кавычки. *Пионер Вася любит грамматику* - что, подлежащее тут "пионер", а "Вася"  как бы и не причем? И сем это отличается от **Колхоз "Красный лапоть" перевыполнил план по добыче навоза*? Все-таки такие вещи надо смотреть у грамматистов, в специализированных изданиях. А коли академическая грамматика о какой-то особой роли кавычек умалчивает, то и нечего кавычки (число орфографическую вещь) ставить впереди  грамматики. .

Comment: Если непонятно, я считаю тут подлежащим всю конструкцию. А если уж исходить из позиции Бельчикова, то не по причине наличия или отсутствия кавычек, а как постулат какой-то оригинальной грамматической системы, что подлежащим может евояться того одно, главное слово во всей группе подлежащего..

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение, мне показалась интересной мысль о том, что можно считать подлежащим сочетания слов «пионер Вася, врач Петров». Я думаю, что такой вариант в принципе возможен, но в то же время чаще возникают ситуации, когда семантика или грамматика заставляют нас в таких сочетаниях ВЫДЕЛЯТЬ главное и зависимое слово (приложение), причем для одного и того же сочетания в разных случаях выбор может быть разным.

Comment: С точки зрения семантики, пионер – это приложение, так как это только одно из определений Васи, что и грамматически соответствует препозиции слова. В предложении «Врач Петрова закончила прием» согласование делается со вторым словом, именно его мы считаем подлежащим. Но: «Врач Петрова – хороший специалист», здесь согласование делается с первым словом, грамматически «врач» - это подлежащее.

Comment: Что касается кавычек, то важны не кавычки,  а то, что выражение в кавычках при наличии родового слова НЕ СКЛОНЯЕТСЯ, поэтому оно играет роль приложения/несогласованного определения, а согласование делается для родового слова/подлежащего.

Comment: *Что касается кавычек, то важны не кавычки,* - Интересные пироги. ))) Вы же всю вашу аргументацию строили исключительно на кавычках. Тогда определитесь, зачем вам нужен был источник вот  такового вот рода: *где ясно обозначены синтаксические функции слов в сочетаниях с именем собственным, заключенным в кавычки?*  если кавычки не нужны, то открывайте любой курс академической грамматики - и смотрите там, что такое подлежащее.

Comment: Так ОЧЕВИДНО ЖЕ, что заключенное  в кавычки слово при наличии родового слова не склоняется. Здесь главное то, что "не склоняется".

Comment: Послушайте, ничего очевидного в мире нет. Не склоняется говорите? А в каком падеже у нас *подлежащее* находится, не напомните? Если главное *то, что не склоняется*?